# Windows build is looking for a .lib when compiling Cython extension with wrapped dll

Tags: python, c, windows, cython

I'm trying to compile a Cython extension which wraps a .dll. I've put the dll (`lonlat_bng.dll`) in the same directory as the source .pyx/.c, and can compile the extension correctly on Linux and OSX. However, Windows is failing to compile it, and giving me the following error (complete build output [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/urschrei/convertbng/build/1.0.8/job/bqfnxye4pfrsqlu2#L139)):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I. -Iconvertbng -IC:\Python27.10-x64\include -IC:\Python27.10-x64\PC /Tcconvertbng/cutil.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\convertbng/cutil.obj
cutil.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:. /LIBPATH:convertbng /LIBPATH:C:\Python27.10-x64\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27.10-x64\PCbuild\amd64 lonlat_bng.lib /EXPORT:initcutil build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\convertbng/cutil.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\convertbng\cutil.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\convertbng\cutil.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\convertbng\cutil.pyd.manifest
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'lonlat_bng.lib'
```

My `setup.py` `Extension` definition looks like so:

```
# suffix is either .pyx or .c, depending on whether Cython is available
Extension("convertbng.cutil",
           sources=["convertbng/cutil" + suffix],
           libraries=["lonlat_bng"],
           include_dirs=['.', 'convertbng'],
           library_dirs=['.', 'convertbng']
)
```

I'm not sure what else I should be doing here…

Comment: You should be supplying the corresponding .lib for the .dll. This is how linking on Windows works.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, this is embarrassing.

Comment: I've been struggling on this issue for 3 days now. The VS compiler outputs a `.dll` if I set my cmake file to SHARED and an `.lib` file if I set it to STATIC... However, using the (static) lib file raises a linker error since it's not a dynamic lib. Any ideas on that?

Comment: while this is real embarrassing that windows needs both .dll and .lib, how to fix this

Comment: @bactone ensure that the corresponding `.lib` file exists in the same place as the `.dll`.

Comment: @urschrei thanks, I got it ,since Cython has to compile, so .lib is neccessory for link.